# JSON error with square brackets

Tags: java, xml, json

I have XML file looking like this

```
<Reading>
<Item Month="_October.xml">
    <kWhReading Firstday="1" />
    <kWhReading Lastday="552" />
</Item>
</Reading>
```

Then using this line of code

`JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) JSONSerializer.toJSON( json.toString() );`

I got this

`[{"@Month":"_October.xml","kWhReading":[{"@Firstday":"1"},{"@Lastday":"552"}]}]`

Then, using this

`JSONObject jsonobject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(0);`

I got this

`{"@Month":"_October.xml","kWhReading":[{"@Firstday":"1"},{"@Lastday":"552"}]}`

Now the problem is, I want to get the value of `Lastday` from `kWhReading` using

`JSONObject readingkWhLast = jsonobject.getJSONObject("kWhReading");`

but it doesn't work and it threw exception

```
net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["kWhReading"] is not a JSONObject.
at net.sf.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:2058)
at com.syntronic.bean.RecentUsage.doPost(RecentUsage.java:82)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am pretty sure it has to do with the square brackets that enclosed `Firstday` and `Lastday` but I am not sure how to remove that. Anyone can help me here?

Comment: Looks like `kWhReading` is a `JSONArray`, not a `JSONObject`.

Comment: Yeah thought so too but I don't know how to access the array to get the second value in the array to be stored into `readingkWhLast`

Answer (score 0):

Never used the JSON library, but this should be on the right track

```
JSONObject readingkWhLast = jsonobject.getJSONArray("kWhReading").get(1);
```

From your `jsonobject` retrieve the `JSONArray` named `"kWhReading"` and then retrieve the element at offset 1 (the second object).

This is all in the API documentation. You really should step back and read the docs thoroughly so you understand the capabilities of the library.

Comment: I'm sorry, it still throw the same exception as above that "kWhReading" is not a JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get jsonArray:

```
[{"@Month":"_October.xml","kWhReading":[{"@Firstday":"1"},{"@Lastday":"552"}]}]
```

Then, you need to use getJSONObject() with an index number to get an element within that array.  The second one is "kWhReading", so:

```
JSONObject kWhReadObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1);
```

That should put you here:

```
{"kWhReading":[{"@Firstday":"1"},{"@Lastday":"552"}]}
```

To get the value of kWhReading (which is itself an array):

```
JSONArray kWhReadArray = kWhReadObject.getJSONArray("kWhReading");
```

Now you're here:

```
[{"@Firstday":"1"},{"@Lastday":"552"}]
```

Back to index numbers.  Again, you want the second one:

```
JSONObject lastDayObj = kWhReadArray.getJSONObject(1);
```

And finally:

```
String lastDay = lastDayObj.getString("@Lastday");
```

The docs are here: http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONArray.html